# Stripe / Stripe.net invoice.payment_succeeded does not include Subscription details

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I am conducting a simple localhost test using stripe CLI.
When I execute the command:

```
 stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded
```

My local webhook picks everything up perfectly and the test data they generate is sent to me. The only issue I have is when the code is deserialized:

```
 if (stripeEvent.Type == "invoice.payment_succeeded")
    {
      Invoice successInvoice = (Invoice)stripeEvent.Data.Object;
      ...
```

The object stripeEvent (of type Invoice) does not have a subscription value for it, or a subscription id, for me to map back to what subscription the customer is under.

Sure, I can see the invoice amount, but I'd like to know more details now on this item.
I was reading something about how Stripe will send over a successful invoice charge but may not initially include subscription details on it, but that concerns me since I want to know the associated subscription.

Any ideas? Am I looking at the wrong webhook event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I just figured it out - if you are testing using the CLI, you need to first create a subscription i.e.

`stripe trigger customer.subscription.created`

and then once you do this, if you then execute your payment

`stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded`

Doing it in this order will then ensure the ID comes in (but not the whole subscription object). but that's ok - you can fetch the whole subscription using the ID like so:

```
 if (successInvoice.SubscriptionId != null)
                {
                    var service = new SubscriptionService();
                    var subscription = service.Get(successInvoice.SubscriptionId);

                    if (subscription != null)
                    {
                        var plan = subscription.Plan; //do stuff with plan
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Invoice object definitely has a reference to the Subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object?lang=dotnet#invoice_object-subscription

It's true that the webhook event that describes the Invoice won't contain many details on the Subscription, but you can then either [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve?lang=dotnet) the Subscription by using the aforementioned ID or retrieve the Invoice from the API whilst [expanding the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/expand).

Comment: I actually just figured it out - if you are testing using the CLI, you need to first create a subscription i.e. stripe trigger customer.subscription.created and then once you do this, if you then execute stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded the ID comes in and you can fetch the whole subscription